# How to embed videos in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, video

I want to develop single page application. It is a video portal, where users can login, see video listings, navigate to a single video, rate videos and can perform all media related tasks for example: Play, Pause, Adjust volume and seek video position.

Since there is `<video>` tag in `HTML5`, Is it possible to use `HTML5` tags inside `app.component.html` to embed videos?
Or could it be a library that I have to install it from `angular2` and then  call it inside `app.component.ts` file?
Or maybe there is another way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to involve Angular, unless you find a need. Inside of your Angular template you can use **any** HTML tags, as long as they are supported by the browsers you wish to support.

Simply include the HTML5 `<video>` tag in your `app.component.html` template and point the src attribute to the file location of your video -

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

---

*Example was copied from the [W3Schools HTML Video tag page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)*

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer to explain that you can use any HTML tags in Angular. Don't be confused, Angular is nothing more than a JavaScript framework that adds a ton of great web-application centric features that make building web applications easier.

Comment: it is working, but the source to the file is not working, even-though the video is in the same file of the `app.component.html`, `<source src="Getting_Started_With_React.js.mp4" type="video/mp4">`, I have this error: `GET http://localhost:4200/Getting_Started_With_React.js.mp4 404 (Not Found)`, what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure your file is named `Getting_Started_With_React.js.mp4`? It seems a bit weird that you'd have a `.js` extension on your video file.

Comment: The video file has to be in the same folder like "index.html" or a subfolder of it, because this is the folder, that contains the static assets.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I changed the name of the video into `react.mp4`, and the code is like that `<source src="./react.mp4" type="video/mp4">`, and it is in the same file of index.html, but still working@Trent

Comment: Working or not working? If it is not working, maybe try `src="react.mp4"` and if not send what your folder structure looks like.

Comment: @ZainabHammami Try changing the filename? call it `test.mp4? Also does the port `4200` need to be used, why not just `http://your_IP_here/test.mp4`?

Comment: I know this is ultra super late (meaning this comment is for random googlers :) ), but you have to add your video to `/src/assets` folder. Everything inside `/src` is masked on build ( for example, your `.spec.ts` are NOT in `/dist` and your .mp4 was masked out too.)

Answer (score 2):

Just include the HTML5  tag in your component.html

```
<video width="xx" height="xx" controls>
    <source src="yourVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```