# How to embed a local video file in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

My question is similar to  this question:
[How to embed videos in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341641/how-to-embed-videos-in-angular2/45341719)
except that I want to embed a local video file location on my PC.
I used the same code and just replaced the https: link with my local file link ( file:///home/user/sample.mp4 ) but now it is not working (video does not play). There is no error message.
This same code works with the https link but not with the local video file link. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Websites cannot use `file://` URIs to access local content on your computer. This is to prevent websites from trying to read, e.g. `C:\Users\you\Desktop\passwords.txt`. The only way for a web-application to access local files is through `<input type="file" />`. The JavaScript `FileSystem` API is non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem

Comment: I am using linux

Comment: Your desktop OS is irrelevant. Websites running in a browser cannot access your local filesystem, even if they are being served from `http://localhost`.

Comment: No, because that won't work either. You don't seem to understand the concept of how browsers restrict access to the local filesystem :S

Comment: Any sample code to do this?

Comment: There is no sample code! You **can't** do this! It's impossible by-design for security purposes!

Comment: No, I was referring to your first comment that the only way to do this is through <input type = "file" />. Do you have any sample code for that?